# Numbering in revtex4

Tags: numbering, revtex

I use revtex for my paper, and the sections are numbered as I. II. (roman), but when I use `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`, I get sth like (I.1), but I'd like it to be like (1.1), I looked around but didn't find anything to change it...

So if anybody can help, I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: In the `revtex4` class sections are numbered with Roman numerals; I don't think it's a good idea using two different representations for the same number.

Comment: How come? It just looks nicer this way imo...

Comment: Your readers may be puzzled about what the first number means, since they are in "Section I" and not in "Section 1".

Comment: Dunno, I don't think that will confuse the readers (not that it will be many of them since it's for a seminar, and I kinda think that only my mentor and professors in charge of the seminar will read it :\)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{document}

\section{aaa}

\begin{equation}1=2\end{equation}

\section{aaa}

\begin{equation}1=2\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Jup, that seems to does the trick :)